# ¿Como ejecutar una function dando click en un botón?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo un input de tipo button, lo que sucede es que quiero que al darle click se ejecute una function la cual tiene dentro otra function en lenguaje Ajax, pero no se ejecuta nada del codigo al darle click, al menos que mostrara errores pero no lo hace
Este es el botón

```
<input type="button" name="login" id="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-success col-12">
```

Y este esta es la function que quiero ejecutar

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#login').click(function(){
        var user = ('#user').val();
        var pass = ('#pass').val();
        if($.trim(user).length > 0 && $.trim(pass).length > 0){
          $.ajax({
            url:"action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{user:user, pass:pass},
            cache:"false",
            beforeSend:function(){
              $('#login').val("Conectando...");
            },
            success:function(){
              if(data="1"){
                $(location).attr('href', './indexUser.php');
              } else {
                $("#result").html("<div class='alert alert-dismissible alert-danger'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><strong>¡Error!</strong> Las credenciales son erroneas.</div>");
              }
            }
          });
        };
      });
    });
  </script>
Hice algunas pruebas colocando que se mostrara una alerta al dar click en el botón pero tampoco funcionaba, eso me lleva a pensar que es error de sintaxis, agradecería que me puedan ayudar
Aqui coloco los Scripts que estoy importando, quizás sirvan de algo
```

Comment: Te falta el $ en ('#user').val()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea una funcion donde puedas llamar todo el codigo:

```
function FuncionEjecutar() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login').click(function(){
        var user = ('#user').val();
        var pass = ('#pass').val();
        if($.trim(user).length > 0 && $.trim(pass).length > 0){
        $.ajax({
            url:"action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{user:user, pass:pass},
            cache:"false",
            beforeSend:function(){
            $('#login').val("Conectando...");
            },
            success:function(){
            if(data="1"){
                $(location).attr('href', './indexUser.php');
            } else {
                $("#result").html("<div class='alert alert-dismissible alert-danger'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><strong>¡Error!</strong> Las credenciales son erroneas.</div>");
            }
            }
        });
        };
    });
    }); 
}
```

Agrega onclick en el boton para ejecuar funciones:

```
<input type="button" name="login" id="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-success col-12" onclick="FuncionEjecutar();">
```

Comment: No es necesario, con esta línea $('#login').click(function() funciona bien.

Comment: Pero sigue sin funcionar el boton. Podrías darme otra solución por favor?, Ya añadí los $ faltantes que me dijiste

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta, intenta crear una función y agregar todo el código dentro, luego la llamas con onclick. Hay te deje un ejemplo

Comment: Si esto no funciona, probablemente sea un problema con la libreria jquery, puede que la pagina no lo este leyendo correctamente.

Comment: Si esto no funciona, probablemente sea un problema con la libreria jquery, puede que la pagina no lo este leyendo correctamente.

Comment: Ya lo coloqué, creo que es lo que dices de la librería jquery, la idea sería colocarl los archivos en la misma carpeta verdad?

Comment: Debería tener una estructura definida de los archivos y cuando los vallas a llamar poner la ruta absoluta.
puede crear una carpeta donde se encuentra su proyecto con el nombre js y hay agregar todos los scripts .js. Despues los puede llamar desde index,php de esta forma `<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: de esta forma ya no tendría que usar la función que le indique, con solo el código que tiene ya seria suficiente.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya funcionó, se ejecuta lo que está dentro de la funcion, le agradezco mucho